# how to bind a domain to AWS cloudfoundry by IP or some other way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry, reverse-dns

I'm working on a project based on Tencent WeChat and using AWS's server. Because the China government's regulations, we need a domain with ICP license to connected Tencent server. However, AWS's domain(us-east.cf.yaas.io) haven't ICP license in China. So we applied a new domain(like abc.com) with the ICP license in China.

But I found our service's public IP address in AWS is not fixed . And I only can access AWS by cf command (cloudfoundry) and have no authority to add domain to our space in cloudfoundry. So, how should I configure DNS resolution to make our domain(like abc.com) mapping to AWS's server?

By the way, at my domain's(like abc.com) DNS resolution provider(Alibaba), I tried a method called "CNAME" and I maped our domain(like abc.com) to AWS's domain(us-east.cf.yaas.io). it seems that our domain have mapping to AWS's domain like below snapshot
[image]

I pinged our sub-domain, it can mapping to aws's domain but it still not work by 404 error.
And if I ping our service in aws directly, it's not the same like below:

[image]

If AWS have some rule to filter this kind of traffic? If YES, how should I bind our domain to AWS's server? A fixed public IP or some other way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like you need to create a cf domain (you need to register your domain abc.com with Cloud Foundry using the `cf create-domain` command). If you do not have the necessary permissions you should ask the administrator of your Cloud Foundry deployment (or the appropriate person) to create one for you.
2. You must also create a route using `cf create-route` to tell the router what app it should point your new domain to.

Please refer to the relevant [Cloud Foundry docs](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html).